# Конкатенация статическиx свойств в классе

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему я не могу сконкатенировать свойства в классе?

```
class Config{
    public static $name        = 'STRING';
    public static $path        = '/tmp/'.self::$name;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как и любая другая статическая переменная PHP, статические свойства могут инициализироваться только используя литерал или константу, **выражения же недопустимы**. Таким образом вы можете инициализировать статическое свойство например целым числом или массивом, но не сможете указать другую переменную, результат вызова функции или объект.

[Официальный источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties)

Но зато с версии >=5.6 возможно задание **констант** с помощью выражений. Поэтому можно сделать так:

```
class Config {
    const ONE = 1;

    // С версии PHP 5.6.0
    const TWO = self::ONE * 2;
    const THREE = self::ONE + self::TWO;
    const SENTENCE = 'The value of THREE is '.self::THREE;
}
echo Config::SENTENCE;
```

тобишь как вариант решения: заменить статику на константы

Comment: Ага спасибо,можно было бы использовать простые свойства не статические,но в моем случае объект нет смысла создавать,так как конфиг общий класс